# AnkhSvn - SVN commit window do not bring in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, ankhsvn

When I right click in solution explorer then click the "Commit..." menu item, Svn commit window do not bring.

I can not see the commit window. If I click anywhere in visual studio I can hear show dialog sound. But I can not see commit window.

How can I solve this?

Setup:
AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio 2.3.10509.1073 
Viusal studio 2010 and SP1 installed.
I have two monitor

Comment: At popular request we added a feature that keeps the size and locations of some specific dialogs. In a later AnkhSVN version we added a few more verifications to check if the stored values make sense before re-using them. I would recommend upgrading to a more recent AnkhSVN.

Comment: I was uninstall plugin and reinstall. But it did not solve. So uninstalling do not clear stored values? Also I use plugin in my office. (10 client, 1 server) We worry about version difference problem. Is upgrading causes any problem?

Comment: This problem was fixed in AnkhSVN in February 2012, but your version of AnkhSVN is from October 2011. If you want to stay on the now unsupported 2.3 versions I would recommend upgrading to the last 2.3 daily that you can get on http://ankhsvn.net/daily/2.3.x. But it would be better to switch to a supported 2.4 or 2.5 release. (AnkhSVN 2.5 is based on Subversion 1.8.X; 2.3 and 2.4 on Subversion 1.7.X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so strange. I try to bring commit window again that right click in solution explorer then click the "Commit..." menu item. 
Then I just use <kbd>window</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> combination. Commit window appear again.

Thanks Bert Huijben